# Login functionality in reactjs using the firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

[image: project image]

I am trying to create a project in that login functionality is good and working properly but when I logged in and refreshed the screen the logout button disappears and the login link will come and then again logout button will come.to understand perfectly watch the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UvTPXPvHf4EhcrifxDEfPuPN0ojUV_mN/view?usp=sharing, this is because of

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext()
//useauth will return the AuthContext
export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export const Authprovider = ({ children }) => {
  var name
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    name = user
  })
  const [currentuser, setcurrentuser] = useState(name)
  const [load, setload] = useState(true)

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setcurrentuser(user)
      setload(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentuser,
    signup,
    login,
    load,
  }

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

I wrapped the AuthProvider component around the app component so that I can use the values like current user .
in Header component where login link, logout button is there

```
 const { currentuser, load } = useAuth()
  const logout = () => {
    try {
      auth.signOut().then(() => {
        console.log('logged out')
      })
    } catch {
      alert('logout is not possible')
    }
  }
//some code
  {currentuser ? (
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
          ) : (
            <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
          )}
```

if there is a current user then the logout button will appear otherwise login link will appear but when refreshing there is some problem I tried many ways now I am out of ideas. "Even I refresh the page when logged in the logout button should not disappear" can you tell me how to do this?
to understan watch the video in the link

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: good, try to accept the answer and give it an upVote if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not using `load state` try this:

```
//some code
  { load ? <div>loading</div> 
         : currentuser ? (
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
          ) : (
            <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
          )}
```